# How to use multiple expressions in single case statement?

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Model1 struct {
    ID string
}
type Model2 struct {
    ID string
}

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan Model1)
    close(ch1)
    checkIfChannelClosed(ch1)
    ch2 := make(chan Model2)
    close(ch2)
    checkIfChannelClosed(ch2)

}

func checkIfChannelClosed(ch interface{}) bool {

    if reflect.TypeOf(ch).Kind() != reflect.Chan {

        fmt.Println("only channels can be closed")
        return false
    }
    ok := true
    if ch == nil {
        return false
    }

    switch v := ch.(type) {
    case chan Model1:
        select {
        case _, ok = <-v: // Line 26
        default:
        }
    case chan Model2:
        select {
        case _, ok = <-v:
        default:
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println("Invalid case")
    }

    if ok {
        fmt.Println("channel is open")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("channel is closed")
    }
    return ok
}
```

---

GoLang compiler does not allow to write multiple expressions in case statement(as shown below). Goal is to avoid redundant code for `select`:

```
switch v := ch.(type) {
case chan Model1, chan Model2:
    select {
    case _, ok = <-v:
    default:
    }
default:
    fmt.Println("Invalid case")
}
```

---

How to use multiple expressions with case statement?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Am using `interface{}` as function parameter, because am passing channel type argument to `checkIfChannelClosed`. Do you suggest a better function signature for `checkIfChannelClosed` to pass channel types?

Comment: The second snippet of code correctly uses multiple types in a type switch case.  The problem is that `v` has type `interface{}` in the case block, not a channel type.

Comment: @Cerise Limón `v` has type `chan Model1` or `chan Model2` after performing `ch.(type)` in type switch. Correct me.

Comment: See https://go.dev/play/p/Mr40aDSIRGk

Comment: @Cerise Limón if v has interface{} type then how first code snippet is working with syntax `<-v` in line 26?

Comment: @overexchange I think it's because having multiple type cases will turn the type of `v` back to `interface{}`. In your original switch case statements, the type of `v` matches the type in the case. https://go.dev/play/p/vj5O38DtgC8

Comment: @rchome OK. So, we cannot have multiple expression in single case statement

Comment: @CeriseLimón Do you suggest to maintain case statement with single expression, each?

Comment: I am trying to point out that the body of the question answers the question in the title.   Your actual question is “How to minimize code duplication when receiving from multiple channel types passed as an interface{}?”  Jacob has a good answer to that question.

Comment: @CeriseLimón As I mentioned here, Jacob solution does not work for open channels...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416653/how-to-use-multiple-expressions-in-single-case-statement?noredirect=1#comment124477566_70417063

Answer (score 1):

I read this in "The Go programming language" chapter 7.13:

*In this style, the emphasis is on the concrete types that satisfy the interface, not on the interface’s methods (if indeed it has any),and there is no hiding of information.*

So, i think x.(Type) return a concrete type,if you use a multicase in a swith x:=x.(Type), what happend in the follow code?

```
switch v := ch.(type) {
case chan Model1,int:
    //do something
}
```

just use the reflect.value to do this:

```
func checkIfChannelClosed(ch interface{}) bool {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(ch)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Chan {
        fmt.Println("only channels can be closed")
        return false
    }

    _, ok := v.TryRecv()
    if ok{
        fmt.Println("recv value from channel..")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("channel is closed or receive cannot finish without blocking")
    }

    return ok
}
```

Comment: Note that, like the original (non-working) variant, this (a) blocks until a value is read or EOF (end of channel) is reached; (b) discards the value read, if not at end of channel. It's the right answer to the question as asked, but Go as a language says not to ask the question in the first place. :-)

Comment: @torek If channel is open, then this code does not work, because `// If the receive cannot finish without blocking, x is the zero Value and ok is false.`

Comment: That's not what [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Recv) says. Er, wait, sorry: I misread the call as `Recv`. He is calling `TryRecv`. So this variant doesn't block, but it will still eat one received value, if the receive succeeds. Calling `Recv` will block.

Comment: @torek Goal is not to block, this is the reason, we are using `select`

Comment: In that case, you can use reflect's [`func (Value) Select`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Select), providing it with a channel that you know will have a value on it so that the select itself won't block, along with the channel you want to test. However this too will eat a value out of the channel. It's also difficult to use because it may choose your channel-with-value and you'll need to loop.